# pool of python coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

## Task

control how much coroutines are running simultaneously with ability to stop the process from inside.

#### Use case

when scraping websites you want to control how much memory program consumes and how much load on target it produces.

#### Usage

1. create an instance
2. call `attach_coroutines_generator` to attach some generator which will create new coroutines from queue which is accessible from these coroutines (for example, every coroutine downloads html and queues new downloads for extracted links)
3. call `run` method

#### More description

`_sleep` method, `_do_stop` and `stop_gracefully` all exists to allow code inside `_runner` method stop `run` method call (because we can't cancel future from its child).

When runner catches `StopIterationError` it is put on sleep for `delay` seconds.

When some "runner" realizes that every other runner is put on sleep, it updates `_do_stop` attribute so all runners will break their while-loops.

#### Questions

- I'm not sure about appropriate naming and typing.
- Security issues?
- Is there other/better ways to do the same?

### Code

```
import asyncio

class RunnersPool:

    def __init__(self, pool_size: int, delay: float =1., enable_auto_stop=True):
        self._pool_size = pool_size
        self._delay = delay
        self._auto_stop_enabled = enable_auto_stop

        self._do_stop = False
        self._active_counter = 0
        self._delayed_counter = 0

        self._coroutines_generator = None
        self._runners = None

    # ----------------
    #  runner methods

    async def _runner(self) -> None:
        self._active_counter += 1
        while True:
            try:
                coroutine = next(self._coroutines_generator)
            except StopIteration:
                await self._sleep()
                if not self.is_running and self._auto_stop_enabled:
                    break
            else:
                try:
                    await coroutine
                except Exception as exc:
                    self.handle_exception(exc, coroutine)
        self._active_counter -= 1

    async def _sleep(self) -> None:
        if self._delayed_counter + 1 == self._pool_size:
            self.stop_gracefully()
            return

        self._delayed_counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(self._delay)
        self._delayed_counter -= 1

    #  end
    # ----------------

    async def run(self):
        if not self._coroutines_generator:
            raise RuntimeError('coroutines_generator not attached yet')

        self._runners = asyncio.gather(*[
            self._runner() for _ in range(self._pool_size)
        ])
        await self._runners

    def handle_exception(self, exception: Exception, coroutine: Coroutine):
        raise exception

    def cancel(self):
        self._runners.cancel()

    def stop_gracefully(self):
        self._do_stop = True

    def attach_coroutines_generator(self, coroutines_generator: Iterable[Coroutine]):
        self._coroutines_generator = coroutines_generator

    @property
    def pool_size(self) -> int:
        return self._pool_size

    @property
    def delay(self) -> float:
        return self._delay

    @property
    def is_running(self) -> bool:
        return not self._do_stop

    @property
    def auto_stop_enabled(self) -> bool:
        return self._auto_stop_enabled

    @property
    def delayed_runners(self) -> int:
        return self._delayed_counter

    @property
    def active_runners(self) -> int:
        return self._active_counter
```

#### Example usage

```
class SmartQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = collections.deque()

    def put(self, x):
        self.queue.append(x)

    def get(self):
        return self.queue.popleft()

    def __next__(self):
        if self.queue:
            return self.get()
        else:
            raise StopIteration


async def main():
    sq = SmartQueue()

    async def cor(num):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(num)
        if num > 0:
            sq.put(cor(num - 1))

    for i in range(1, 10+1):
        sq.put(cor(i))

    r = RunnersPool(5)
    r.attach_coroutines_generator(sq)

    await r.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: From experience, coroutines are not built to act like this; they're event-based processors (they process something when the next event fires off). You're adding all the functionality that is already inherent in threads.  I also have a pet peeve (pithy, I know), people putting "smart" in front of things :-)

Comment: @C.Harley Pool exists to delay coroutines execution by using queue. In case of scraping you have too many start urls to run them all simultaneously (because of a lot of connections and memory usage). And about "SmartQueue" - it's just a quck way to name something )

Comment: Yes, I can see what you're doing, however I'm pointing out that Coroutines have a completely different intent and use. I'd recommend studying the difference and trying to do your assigned task using Threads. Give it a try and see the differences in task allocation, interaction with the queue and built-in functionality.